# Postgres add values in timestamp

Tags: postgresql

How could I go about a query that where all parts of the timestamp excluding the year add up to 50,

for example in my database testdb I have my column with a **string** timestamp, in that column I have my timestamp **strings** for example,

```
2016-03-01 07:13:21
2019-07-03 04:04:49
```

etc so they are separated by the -

so when I query my database, `Select timestamp from testdb where.... = 50` I want to see where the individual timestamp strings from all the rows that add up to 50

Comment: What data type is that column? But I don't understand what the actual _output_ is you are after. Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the expected result?

Comment: Done, hopefully that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: 3 + 1 + 7 + 13 + 21 is 45, 7 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 49 is 67, I don't know how you can make those equal 50

Comment: I still don't understand what "adding up" refers to for a single timestamp value (or even multiple timestamp values). Btw: storing a timestamp in a text column is a **really** bad idea to begin with

Comment: Its not to make them add to 50, its a query so it will only show those that are equal to 50

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It will just query the whole column take each row individually, remove the year, and then add up the day,month,hour,minute and the second and then if that amounts to 50 it will just display those rows that meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove the year, and then add up the day,month,hour,minute and the second and then if that amounts to 50 it will just display those rows that meet the criteria

So you first need to convert your string to a timestamp using e.g. `to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

From there you can extract each part of the timestamp using [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
select *
from the_table
where extract(month from to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
    + extract(day from to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
    + extract(hour from to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
    + extract(minute from to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
    + extract(second from to_timestamp(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')  = 50
```

---

It's a **really** bad idea to store timestamp values in `text` (or `varchar`) columns. They should be stored in columns defined as `timestamp` or better `timestamptz`